# Is an Android app that uses both Holo theme and google cast possible?

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

My app is already using Holo but when I added chromecast support it was required that I use the v7 support ActionBarActivity or at least FragmentActivity. Both of these require me to use an AppCompat theme from what I can tell. Is that true? Does adding a feature like google cast really require you to change your theme? The reason I resist changing to an appcompat theme is because it breaks allot of the custom styling I created.

Comment: In general, the stock `MediaRouteActionProvider` from `mediarouter-v7` requires `appcompat-v7`. I have [a cross-port of `mediarouter-v7` that works with the native action bar](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-mediarouter), avoiding the `appcompat-v7` requirement. However, I have only used it with `RemotePlaybackClient`, not the Cast SDK. While I would expect it to work, as the saying goes, YMMV.

Comment: Yes, using the Cast SDK requires you to use the appcompat libraries. Although CommonsWare has created a version of the mediarouter-v7 that does't have that dependency, it is strongly recommended for you to use the official mediarouter-v7 and change your theme to use appcompat; the reason would be (1) any bug fixes that goes into the official one may not find its way to the unofficial one and (2) if you want to support Material + anything older (even holo), you need to use the appcompat lib anyway. That said, it is a choice that each developer has to make on his/her own.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Yeah I would rather stay using official libs. If I am switching from Holo to using AppCompat then can I avoid the extra res/values-xx/styles.xml files by going ahead and adopting the material design stuff with toolbars instead of action bars?

Comment: I was just looking at this the other day! It'd be great if there was an official version of the Media Router library that was for API 14(?) + and didn't need AppCompat.

Comment: In the end I just bit the bullet and adopted app compat and used the api-21 so I also ended up with the basis for material design. It meant allot of work just to add chromecast but oh well. It seems as they add features there will be continued new reasons to use the support versions of the Activity class any how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in conclusion it sounds like for now the answer is no its not possible. Based on the comments from Ali and commonsware. At least without using unofficial sdk code which I do not want to do.